# Create tag without privileges

Tags: feature-request, tags

Like the ability to submit edits for approval without privilege shouldn't there be an ability to do the same with Tags? Especially for this site with new games (and therefore tags) coming out monthly new users might get put off if their game doesn't have a tag.

Comment: Good suggestion. We have the same problem on Android with new or uncommon devices.